# Is there a registry of which Windows functions returns what error codes?

Tags: winapi, msdn

I'm on the troubleshooting end of a obscure problem and all I have is this error code and I need to work backwards from that, it would really help my cause if I could identify what Windows function returns what error code, MSDN has a fairly extensive listing of errors returned by functions but I can't do a reverse lookup...

Comment: Do you have an error number or a `#define`'s name?

Comment: @Deanna ERROR_DIRECTORY 267 (0x0000010B), I believe the get GetTemp... functions return these error codes amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) source code and search it for the error. Obviously it's not 1:1 with actual Windows, but might help, if you have no other clue.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with the [`errlook.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh0w11%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) utility that tries to give you a friendly error message given an error code.

The Exchange team have also released a [small tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) that you pass the error number to, and it shows you the appropriate headers, sometimes with descriptions:

```
C:\>Err.exe c0000005
# for hex 0xc0000005 / decimal -1073741819 :
  STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION                                       ntstatus.h
# The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at
# "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".
  USBD_STATUS_DEV_NOT_RESPONDING                                usb.h
# 2 matches found for "c0000005"
```

Comment: The `net.exe` tool can also be used to look up error messages (`net helpmsg NNN`).